# Почему не получается с preg_match?

Tags: php

пытаюсь спарсить с сайтов партнеров информацию о том, в наличии ли у них товар или нет. Собственно вот код

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://xn----7sblaeg7cgj4a.com.ua/snyato-s-prodazh-za-mart-2017/3339-palto-frak.html');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36');
    $out = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (preg_match("/продан/ui", $out)) {
      var_dump('yes');
    }else{
      var_dump('no');
    }
```

но получаю ответом

```
/var/www/html/curl/index.php:28:string 'no' (length=2)
```

хотя на сайте сеть следующие строки

```
<meta name="description" content="ПРОДАНО" />
...
<div id="short_description_content" class="rte align_justify"><p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>ПРОДАНО</strong></span></p></div>
```

причем `var_dump($out);` выдает страницу полностью

Comment: Какая то дичь там с кодировкой. php не воспринимает загруженную страницу как готовый к обработке utf-8 текст. Не работают многие строковые функции, тот же htmlspecialchars, например. Мне победить проблему в разумное время не удалось. С удовольствием посмотрю на решение, если оно найдётся.

Comment: @iosp смотрите нижнее решение у меня в разовой странице получилось использовать. Но на потоке в yii2 не получилось

Comment: У меня нижнее не работает, даже в порядке исключения. Аномалий в странице кроме BOM  в начале тоже особо нет, принудительное его вырезание так же ничего не дало. Ответ ниже не даёт ответа на то, почему не работает в вашем варианте.

Comment: php-файл то в какой кодировке? Если обозначаете юникод `u`, то и текст в регэкспе должен быть юникод либо hex-представление. Ниже вообще не ответ, ни слова о кодировке в mb_*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поиска конкретного слова рекомендую использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
if (mb_stristr($out, 'продан')) {
    var_dump('yes');
} else {
    var_dump('no');
}
```

Эта функция ищет подстроку "продан" в мультибайтовой кодировке без учёта регистра и работает быстрее, чем поиск по регулярному выражению.
Если вам нужен поиск с учётом регистра, используйте функцию `mb_strstr($out, 'продан')`

Если вам нужно использовать именно регулярные выражения, то уберите модификатор `u`, так как он разбивает строку в юникод и, как результат, не находит указанного слова.

Таким образом, проверка условия должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
if (preg_match('/продан/i', $out)) {
    var_dump('yes');
} else {
    var_dump('no');
}
```